# Select option in sequence

Tags: php, html, jquery

I was wondering if you could help me with a problem that I’m having in realizing my business’ website.
As you can see in my code I already created 6 select options, but I want to make sure that the second select option (and then the third etc.) appears only when I put a value on the first select option and I don’t know how to do it right now.
Here is my code:

```
<div class="case-item">
            <div class="container">
                  <h2 class="title title--h3">I tuoi canotti</h2>
                <br>
                
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                      <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md">
                            <select name="users" id="canotto1" onchange="Canotto(this.value,'Canotto1');">
                                <?php echo $opt->Canotti(); ?>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-1">
                            <a  
                                        style="
                                        background-color: #cc0000;
                                        border-radius: 10px;
                                        border: 0;
                                        color: #fff;
                                        cursor: pointer;
                                        font-size: 0.8rem;
                                        font-weight: 400;
                                        line-height: inherit;
                                        text-transform:uppercase;
                                        overflow: hidden;
                                        padding: 0.4rem 0.6rem;
                                        position: relative;
                                        transition: .4s ease-in-out;
                                        white-space: nowrap;
                                        z-index: 1;" 
                               onclick="EliminaCanotto('Canotto1');">Elimina</a>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <br>
                        
                    <div id="mostra2">
                       <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md">
                            <select name="users" id="canotto2" onchange="Canotto(this.value,'Canotto2');">
                                <?php echo $opt->Canotti(); ?>
                            </select> 
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-1">
                            <a  
                                        style="
                                        background-color: #cc0000;
                                        border-radius: 10px;
                                        border: 0;
                                        color: #fff;
                                        cursor: pointer;
                                        font-size: 0.8rem;
                                        font-weight: 400;
                                        line-height: inherit;
                                        text-transform:uppercase;
                                        overflow: hidden;
                                        padding: 0.4rem 0.6rem;
                                        position: relative;
                                        transition: .4s ease-in-out;
                                        white-space: nowrap;
                                        z-index: 1;" 
                               onclick="EliminaCanotto('Canotto2');">Elimina</a>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                        
                    <br>
                       <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md">
                        <select name="users" id="canotto3" onchange="Canotto(this.value,'Canotto3');">
                                <?php echo $opt->Canotti(); ?>
                            </select> 
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-1">
                            <a  
                                        style="
                                        background-color: #cc0000;
                                        border-radius: 10px;
                                        border: 0;
                                        color: #fff;
                                        cursor: pointer;
                                        font-size: 0.8rem;
                                        font-weight: 400;
                                        line-height: inherit;
                                        text-transform:uppercase;
                                        overflow: hidden;
                                        padding: 0.4rem 0.6rem;
                                        position: relative;
                                        transition: .4s ease-in-out;
                                        white-space: nowrap;
                                        z-index: 1;" 
                               onclick="EliminaCanotto('Canotto3');">Elimina</a>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                <br>
                       <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md">
                        <select name="canotto1" id="canotto4" onchange="Canotto(this.value,'Canotto4');">
                                <?php echo $opt->Canotti(); ?>
                            </select>    
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-1">
                            <a  
                                        style="
                                        background-color: #cc0000;
                                        border-radius: 10px;
                                        border: 0;
                                        color: #fff;
                                        cursor: pointer;
                                        font-size: 0.8rem;
                                        font-weight: 400;
                                        line-height: inherit;
                                        text-transform:uppercase;
                                        overflow: hidden;
                                        padding: 0.4rem 0.6rem;
                                        position: relative;
                                        transition: .4s ease-in-out;
                                        white-space: nowrap;
                                        z-index: 1;" 
                               onclick="EliminaCanotto('Canotto4');">Elimina</a>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    <br>
                       <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md">
                        <select name="canotto5" id="canotto5" onchange="Canotto(this.value,'Canotto5');">
                                <?php echo $opt->Canotti(); ?>
                            </select>    
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-1">
                            <a  
                                        style="
                                        background-color: #cc0000;
                                        border-radius: 10px;
                                        border: 0;
                                        color: #fff;
                                        cursor: pointer;
                                        font-size: 0.8rem;
                                        font-weight: 400;
                                        line-height: inherit;
                                        text-transform:uppercase;
                                        overflow: hidden;
                                        padding: 0.4rem 0.6rem;
                                        position: relative;
                                        transition: .4s ease-in-out;
                                        white-space: nowrap;
                                        z-index: 1;" 
                               onclick="EliminaCanotto('Canotto5');">Elimina</a>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                <br>
                       <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md">
                        <select name="canotto6" id="canotto6" onchange="Canotto(this.value,'Canotto6');">
                                <?php echo $opt->Canotti(); ?>
                            </select>    
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-1">
                            <a  
                                        style="
                                        background-color: #cc0000;
                                        border-radius: 10px;
                                        border: 0;
                                        color: #fff;
                                        cursor: pointer;
                                        font-size: 0.8rem;
                                        font-weight: 400;
                                        line-height: inherit;
                                        text-transform:uppercase;
                                        overflow: hidden;
                                        padding: 0.4rem 0.6rem;
                                        position: relative;
                                        transition: .4s ease-in-out;
                                        white-space: nowrap;
                                        z-index: 1;" 
                               onclick="EliminaCanotto('Canotto6');">Elimina</a>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-1">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-7">
                        <div id="txtHint"></div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>      
            </div>
```

This is the code of the ajax:
`<script> function Canotto(str , can) { if (str == "") { document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = ""; return; } else { var id = <?php echo $_GET['id'] ?>; var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest(); xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() { if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) { document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = this.responseText; } }; xmlhttp.open("GET","Plenum_inserimentoCanotti.php?q=" + str + "&id=" + id + "&can=" + can ,true); xmlhttp.send(); } } </script>`

Comment: This is a Javascript issue yet you have not added any javascript code

Comment: Off topic:  Learn to use classes, those style dumps in the `<a>` tags are just nasty.

Comment: I know that the '<a>' tags are nasty but i'll change them when i will know how to solve the problem i wrote. The problem is that i don't know how to wrote a javascript that can do what i need, some help?

Comment: That's why it's tagged "off topic" :)

Answer (score 0):

As you have not added any Javascript we do not know what the function `Canotto` actually does - does it send an ajax request, do a lookup in an array/json, create content dynamically or other! So - with a minor tweak to the HTMl so that each `select` menu has a unique `dataset` attribute - `data-id` you can look ahead/behind using a couple of simple `sibling selector` type functions ( `findnextselect` and `findpreviousselect` ) to identify the next/previous select menus and set a display property on these found nodes.

Perhaps it'll give an idea how to proceed

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',()=>{
  let col=document.querySelectorAll('select.canotto');

  const findnextselect=(n,expr)=>{
    let s=n.nextElementSibling;
    while(s){
      if(s.matches(expr))return s;
      if(s.tagName.toLowerCase()=='body')return false;
      s=s.nextElementSibling;
    }
  }
  const findpreviousselect=(n,expr)=>{
    let s=n.previousElementSibling;
    while(s){
      if(s.matches(expr))return s;
      if(s.tagName.toLowerCase()=='body')return false;
      s=s.previousElementSibling;
    }
  }

  const changehandler=function(e){
    let i=Number(this.dataset.id);

    let n=findnextselect(this,'select.canotto');
    let p=findpreviousselect(this,'select.canotto');

    if( n && Number( n.dataset.id ) >= i )n.classList.add('active');

  };

  col.forEach(sel=>{
    sel.addEventListener('change',changehandler)
  })            
})
```

```css
select.canotto{display:none;padding:0.5rem;margin:0.5rem}
select.canotto:first-child{display:block}

.active{display:block!important}
```

```html
<select class='canotto' data-id=1 name='users'>
  <option value=1>1
  <option value=2>2
  <option value=3>3
  <option value=4>4
  <option value=5>5
  <option value=6>6
  <option value=7>7
  <option value=8>8
  <option value=9>9
</select>

<select class='canotto' data-id=2 name='users'>
  <option value=1>1
  <option value=2>2
  <option value=3>3
  <option value=4>4
  <option value=5>5
  <option value=6>6
  <option value=7>7
  <option value=8>8
  <option value=9>9
</select>

<select class='canotto' data-id=3 name='users'>
  <option value=1>1
  <option value=2>2
  <option value=3>3
  <option value=4>4
  <option value=5>5
  <option value=6>6
  <option value=7>7
  <option value=8>8
  <option value=9>9     
</select>

<select class='canotto' data-id=4 name='users'>
  <option value=1>1
  <option value=2>2
  <option value=3>3
  <option value=4>4
  <option value=5>5
  <option value=6>6
  <option value=7>7
  <option value=8>8
  <option value=9>9     
</select>
```

Comment: Pro Tip: there is absolutely no advantage/benefit in repeating the option's text as the `value` declaration.

Comment: in this case I know - it was generated in PHP and output copied verbatim just for the demo... in reality the value and text could and likely would be different. I realise that `<option>1` etc would work just fine though

Comment: Thank you so much professor! I've add the ajax now if it could help. Anyway, running your snipplet look ok for what i need. Now i try to insert in my page.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I believe you are looking for. After each canotto1 is clicked, conotto2 is opened and so on.

The code lacked IDS and there were many unecessary element such as onchange. The styling was bad, I used an ID to pass the styling to each  that had that ID.

If you had a clean code, the javascript could have been much shorter and not repeated and you could even use jQuery.

But the code below get the job done.

**Tested and works.**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Hide Show</title>
</head>
    
<body>

<style>
                            #style-select { background-color: #cc0000;
                                        border-radius: 10px;
                                        border: 0;
                                        color: #fff;
                                        cursor: pointer;
                                        font-size: 0.8rem;
                                        font-weight: 400;
                                        line-height: inherit;
                                        text-transform:uppercase;
                                        overflow: hidden;
                                        padding: 0.4rem 0.6rem;
                                        position: relative;
                                        transition: .4s ease-in-out;
                                        white-space: nowrap;
                                        z-index: 1; }

</style>
<div class="case-item">
            <div class="container">
                  <h2 class="title title--h3">I tuoi canotti</h2>
                <br>
                
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                      <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md">
                            <select name="users" id="canotto1">
                                <?php echo $opt->Canotti(); ?>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-1">
                            <a  id="style-select"
                               onclick="hideShowFeature()">Elimina</a>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <br>
                        
                    <div id="mostra2">
                       <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md">
                            <select name="users" id="canotto2">
                                <?php echo $opt->Canotti(); ?>
                            </select> 
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-1">
                            <a  id="style-select"
                               onclick="hideShowFeature2()">Elimina</a>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                        
                    <br>
                       <div class="row" id="mostra3">
                        <div class="col-md">
                        <select name="users" id="canotto3">
                                <?php echo $opt->Canotti(); ?>
                            </select> 
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-1">
                            <a  id="style-select"
                               onclick="hideShowFeature3()">Elimina</a>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                <br>
                       <div class="row" id="mostra4">
                        <div class="col-md">
                        <select name="canotto1" id="canotto4" onchange="Canotto(this.value,'Canotto4');">
                                <?php echo $opt->Canotti(); ?>
                            </select>    
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-1" >
                            <a  id="style-select"
                               onclick="hideShowFeature4()">Elimina</a>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    <br>
                       <div class="row" id="mostra5">
                        <div class="col-md">
                        <select name="canotto5" id="canotto5" onchange="Canotto(this.value,'Canotto5');">
                                <?php echo $opt->Canotti(); ?>
                            </select>    
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-1">
                            <a  id="style-select"
                               onclick="hideShowFeature5()">Elimina</a>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                <br>
                       <div class="row " id="mostra6">
                        <div class="col-md">
                        <select name="canotto6" id="canotto6" onchange="Canotto(this.value,'Canotto6');">
                                <?php echo $opt->Canotti(); ?>
                            </select>    
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-1">
                            <a  id="style-select"
                               >Elimina</a>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-1">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-7">
                        <div id="txtHint"></div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>      
            </div>
<script type="text/javascript">
        
    function hideShowFeature()  {
        if (document.getElementById("canotto1").checked = true) {
            document.getElementById("mostra2").style.display = "block";  
            document.getElementById("mostra3").style.display = "none"; 
            document.getElementById("mostra4").style.display = "none"; 
            document.getElementById("mostra5").style.display = "none"; 
            document.getElementById("mostra6").style.display = "none";          
        }
    }   
    
    function hideShowFeature2() {
    if (document.getElementById("canotto2").checked = true) {
            document.getElementById("mostra2").style.display = "block";  
            document.getElementById("mostra3").style.display = "block"; 
            document.getElementById("mostra4").style.display = "none"; 
            document.getElementById("mostra5").style.display = "none"; 
            document.getElementById("mostra6").style.display = "none"; 
        } 
    }

    function hideShowFeature3() {
    if (document.getElementById("canotto3").checked = true) {
            document.getElementById("mostra2").style.display = "block";  
            document.getElementById("mostra3").style.display = "block"; 
            document.getElementById("mostra4").style.display = "block"; 
            document.getElementById("mostra5").style.display = "none"; 
            document.getElementById("mostra6").style.display = "none"; 
        } 
    }
    
    function hideShowFeature4() {
    if (document.getElementById("canotto4").checked = true) {
            document.getElementById("mostra2").style.display = "block";  
            document.getElementById("mostra3").style.display = "block"; 
            document.getElementById("mostra4").style.display = "block"; 
            document.getElementById("mostra5").style.display = "block"; 
            document.getElementById("mostra6").style.display = "none"; 
        } 
    }
    
    function hideShowFeature5() {
    if (document.getElementById("canotto5").checked = true) {
            document.getElementById("mostra2").style.display = "block";  
            document.getElementById("mostra3").style.display = "block"; 
            document.getElementById("mostra4").style.display = "block"; 
            document.getElementById("mostra5").style.display = "block"; 
            document.getElementById("mostra6").style.display = "block"; 
        } 
    }   
</script>   
<style>
#mostra2 {
    display:none;
}
#mostra3 {
    display:none;
}
#mostra4 {
    display:none;
}
#mostra5 {
    display:none;
}
#mostra6 {
    display:none;
}
</style>
</body>     
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you Rahul! I've tried to use your code but, it show me the next part just when i click on "Elimina" button, i need to see the next select after the previous one have a set value.